# Tablelayout elements are not centered and go off screen

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

When I see the table in android studio, it looks centered but it's not on AVD or my own device.
Here is the image.
[image]

As you can see, the table is slightly off to the right. On the physical devices, the shift is more remarkable. How can I fix this?
I already tried `android:layout_gravity="center"` in table layout.
and `.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` in java file. and both didn't work.

Here is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrl"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/progressBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Llayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TableLayout

        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar">


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_one"
                android:layout_width="118dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
                android:text="@string/one"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_size" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_two"
                android:layout_width="21dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/two"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_size" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_three"
                android:layout_width="27dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/three"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_size" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_four"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/four"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_size" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_five"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/five"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_size" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_six"
                android:layout_width="7dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/six"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_size" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_seven"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/seven"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_size" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_eight"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/eight"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_size" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_nine"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/nine"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_size" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_size" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_zero"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="clip_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/zero"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_size" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
                android:onClick="onclick2"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrl"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/table1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="368dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle"
        android:rotation="0"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"
        android:max="100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:progress="70" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textinprog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/progressBar2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progressBar2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that the widths of the buttons' are hard-coded with certain values while you need to stretch them using `android:stretchColumns="*"` attribute.

And therefore their widths might exceed the width of a phone's screen.

So, in order to have equal width buttons with  `android:stretchColumns="*"`, you also need to change/add the below attributes to every button (except the `zero` button):

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

**Side note:**

There are extra unneeded attributes in the `<TableLayout>`  that can be removed as you already using `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, so you can keep it just like:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar">
```